# ¿Cómo hacer saltos de líneas en Atom automáticamente?

Tags: atom-editor

cuando escribo en Atom, por ejemplo un archivo txt. Normalmente si la línea mide más que la ventana propia de Atom debo de ir hacia el final de esta.
Creo que hay una opción para que si la línea sobrepasa el tope horizontal, se haga un salto de línea automáticamente, vamos que se vaya a ajustando el texto acorde a la ventana.

¿Sabéis dónde está esa opción en Atom?

GRACIAS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tu estás buscando se llama *Soft Wrap* y lo puedes activar desde el panel de configuración, accedes a este aplastando <kbd>cmd + ,</kbd> o <kbd>ctrl + ,</kbd> dependiendo del sistema operativo llegarás a esta vista

Le damos click en *<> Editor*

[image: Vista de ajustes Atom]

Bajamos hasta encontrar el checkbox de *Soft Wrap* lo activamos y listo queda activado por defecto

[image: Pestaña de Editor en Ajustes]

---

Otra opción es ir directo al archivo de configuración, podemos hacerlo aplastando <kbd>cmd + shift + p</kbd> o <kbd>ctrl + shift + p</kbd> y escribimos `config`, y buscamos la opción de *Application: Open Your Config*, la elegimos y se abrirá el archivo `config.cson`

[image: Config]

Buscamos la linea que diga `softWrap: false`, si no existe debemos agregarla al nivel de `editor` agregandole el atributo *true* `softWrap: true`

```
"*":
  editor:
    softWrap: true
```

Comment: Muy bien explicado @KacosPro Gracias!